# Eclipse crashed and won't restart. I don't understand the stack trace

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse crashed and won't restart.
Can someone help me understand what the problem is? The message from the log is below.
I am on Win7 and develop with Android SDKand I recently installed subclipse svn
Thank you very much

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 566 2012-01-24 15:15:54.500
!MESSAGE Cannot set lower sequence number for root (previous: 178, new: 177). Ignoring the new value.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set lower sequence number for root (previous: 178, new: 177). Ignoring the new value.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager$MasterTable.put(SaveManager.java:50)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restoreMasterTable(SaveManager.java:829)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:684)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1527)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2251)
at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
at     org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting (or moving) the .metadata folder from your workspace?

Comment: Just did. Eclipse starts but my workspace is empty

Comment: From the empty workspace, do File > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace. You can select your existing project directories from the resulting dialog.

Comment: Just posted an actual answer... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually move my .metadata folder, restart eclipse (which will recreate the .metadata folder), import existing projects and then shutdown eclipse and restore following folders from the old .metadata to the new:

.metadata\.plugins\:

- org.eclipse.core.runtime
- org.eclipse.debug.core
- org.eclipse.debug.ui
- org.eclipse.search
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor
- org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui

This will restore a lot of settings you had before and save you some time to reset them.
This list is not exhaustive, there are more settings folders that could be restored but for me these were the most useful ones.

Comment: This worked for the IDLDE workbench as well. Thanks! I think it got screwed when I installed regular eclipse to work on a java project, which conflicted with the IDL implementation of it.

Answer (score 29):

Delete the file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap

Comment: Hm, I don't have .snap

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting (or moving) the .metadata folder from your Workspace and see if it fix this.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I had the exact same problem and deleting the file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap did the trick for me.

Comment: this is the best solution for this problem - no need to recreate your old settings after deleting .metadata - worked for me also... +1

Answer (score 0):

My method was the following:

1. backup the whole .plugin folder
2. look at the log what plugins are affected in the stack trace. at the first place, in your case its "org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager ...".
3. search for a folder int the .plugin folder which name match this plugin
4. if it exists, delete it
5. try to start eclipse again, if it doesn't work, go to step 2 but chose the next plugin in the stack trace, eg. "org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace"