# Eclipse with ADT won't start - points at error in /metadata/.log file

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

[EDIT] Other projects load just fine, as I have discovered. This only happens on this one project.

The data in the .log file do not make any sense to me. Here it is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-04-14 09:56:14.874
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (85).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/JSONBourne/bin/jarlist.cache' not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1528)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2502)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2251)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 28 more
```

Anyone with any idea about what's going on? It has to be an Eclipse problem since the project is compiling just fine on AIDE on my Nexus 7. This happened suddenly this morning - Eclipse was working just fine until last night. Needless to say, I'm a bit nervous about this.

Comment: Looks like the save state was corrupted (`org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:710)`, and by a very weird domino effect this causes a core bundle not to load.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993717/eclipse-crashed-and-wont-restart-i-dont-understand-the-stack-trace#16958840) might help you.